# Handle application exit

Tags: windows-8, winjs

I want to run some cleanup code(like unregistering scheduled notifications) when a user quits the application by using the *Alt-F4* or swipe down gesture. Is there any way to handle an application exit in WinJS? I've read the docs for the *WinJS.Application* object but don't see any methods to handle user exits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[There is no special event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464925.aspx) that indicates that an app is being closed:

> There's no special event to indicate that the user has closed an app. After an app has been closed by the user, it's suspended and terminated, entering the **NotRunning** state within about 10 seconds. If an app has registered an event handler for the **Suspending | suspending** event, it is called when the app is suspended. You can use this event handler to save relevant application and user data to persistent storage.

So you'll want to handle a suspend/resume instead. The gory details for handling a suspend are [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465138.aspx), but here's a summary:

1. Register for the [checkpoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br229839.aspx) event that will tell your app that it's being suspended.
2. Save whatever data you need to save in the event handler for that event.
3. Release resources, suspend notifications, etc. in the event handler as well.

On resume, you can check if the app was closed by the user using the [`ApplicationExecutionState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.activation.applicationexecutionstate.aspx) enum. That may or may not be relevant to you, since there doesn't seem to be a way to differentiate why `checkpoint` event was fired and your only option is to save your state in the event handler no matter why it happened.

There are additional suspend/resume guidelines [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465088.aspx), and you may find [this sample app](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/App-activation-events-and-d39c53d5) helpful.