# How can I detect WinRT app exit?

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

Say the user drag the app to the bottom of the screen, I want to run cleanup codes and kill some connections.

How can I do this?

Does it also call the `suspending` event handlers? If so how can I identify regular suspension vs. termination?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes it call the suspending event handler and no you cannot differentiate it. (Even if the app is doing a regular suspension the user can close it while it is suspended and you will no additional event will get called ):

[Here is a doc stating that it go to suspention state before closing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh986968.aspx):

> When the user closes an app by pressing Alt+F4 or using the close
>   gesture, the app is suspended for 10 seconds and then terminated.

Also in windows 8.1 when the user drag down the app [it will not even be terminated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464925.aspx) by default:

> In Windows 8.1 Preview and later, after an app has been closed by the
>   user, the app is only removed from the screen and switch list without
>   being terminated.

Just also note that if your intent is to do some saving, it's better practice to save progressevely rather than waiting for suspension. You can find more information about suspension guidance [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.application.suspending).

Comment: According to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12667498/handle-application-exit) and the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464925.aspx), there is no event called on close. Can you point to some documentation to back up your answer?

Comment: From the answer you linked:
if an app has registered an event handler for the Suspending | suspending event, it is called when the app is suspended. You can use this event handler to save relevant application and user data to persistent storage.

Comment: this is in the Close section of the doc

Comment: Suspension is not the same as close; the OP, in my opinion, is asking about the latter.

Comment: and also when you look at the image on the doc there is no direct arrow from Running to NotRunning it always pass by the suspending state

Comment: yes but what it is saying is that when closing, you have nothing more to do than handle suspend. A better quote from the other answer would be "So you'll want to handle a suspend/resume instead."

Comment: Added a link to another doc were it's a little mote clear

Comment: Yes, this makes sense now after re-reading. Thank you for clearing things up.